# Python: Flatten ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have inherited some python code which has a ndarray which looks as:

```
>>> ARCoeff
Out[6]: array([array([[ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ]])], dtype=object)

>>> ARCoeff.dtype
Out[7]: dtype('O')

>>> ARCoeff.shape
Out[8]: (1,)

>>> type( ARCoeff )
Out[2]: numpy.ndarray
```

How do I extract the array out to something like

```
[ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ]
```

Edit:

Based on the suggestion provided this is what I get:

```
>>> z = ARCoeff.flatten().tolist()

>>> z[0]
Out[19]: array([[ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ]])

>>> z1 = z[0]

>>> type(z1)
Out[21]: numpy.ndarray
```

So, I am back to having an ndarray.

Edit2:

```
>>> np.version.version
Out[31]: '1.8.0'
```

Edit3:

```
>>> z = ARCoeff.flatten().flatten().tolist()
>>> type(z)
Out[38]: list
>>> z1 = z[0]
>>> type(z1)
Out[40]: numpy.ndarray
```

May I please know why my question is being voted down ? I am very new to Python so please bear with me.

Comment: Why would you have that array? rather than just `array([ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ])`. To extract it just type `RCoeff[0][0]`

Comment: Just to be sure, which Python/numpy version are you using?

Comment: I suspect the downvote(s) come from people who don't understand the structure of your array.  But you really should have told us something about where it came from.

Comment: (I didn't downvote it :P) But I'm also curious on how did the OP get that array, or why is he using that structure.

Comment: Is it an import from MATLAB?

Comment: Yes it was originally a mat file which is imported in python. The mat file is a struct with different size arrays.

Comment: That makes this question much more valuable, as is a common mistake when using scipy's `io.loadmat`!

Comment: Any suggestion as to how this import of the mat file be done ?

Comment: You are loading it in the proper way. Is just the way scipy imports matlab's `.mat` files. You need to be careful when loading them.

Comment: And `loadmat` is just coping with the complex data structure that MATLAB saves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reproduce the display of the OP, I have to use:

```
In [83]: x=np.zeros((1,),dtype=object)    
In [84]: x[0]=np.array([[ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ]])
In [85]: x
Out[85]: array([array([[ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ]])], dtype=object)
```

This is not the same as

```
In [75]: a = np.array([np.array([[ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ]])], dtype=object)

In [76]: a
Out[76]: array([[[1.16179327, -0.1721163]]], dtype=object)

In [78]: a.shape
Out[78]: (1, 1, 2)
```

`np.array` tries to convert its inputs into a high dimensional array, and removes most evidence of nested arrays.

From the names, I'm guessing this array comes from a library with a name like `ARC` - I believe that's a mapping library.

In any case, we can pull the inner array out just by indexing:

```
In [86]: x[0]
Out[86]: array([[ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ]])
```

That is now a simple 2d array, which can be flattened or raveled, or reshaped:

```
In [87]: x[0].flatten()
Out[87]: array([ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ])
```

`flatten` does nothing to the original `x` since that is 1d already.

---

I found `ARCoeff` in a MATLAB document

http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/modify-regarima-model-properties.html

A 2d array within an object array is characteristic of how `scipy` loads MATLAB files.

In Octave I can do

```
octave:11> ARCoeff={[1,2,3]};
octave:12> save -7 test.mat ARCoeff
```

and in IPython load the file with `scipy.io.loadmat`

```
In [99]: from scipy.io import loadmat

In [100]: M=loadmat('test.mat')

In [101]: M['ARCoeff']
Out[101]: array([[array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.]])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: >>> x[0].flatten()
Out[65]: array([ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ])
>>> z = x[0].flatten()
>>> type(z)
Out[67]: numpy.ndarray

Comment: So, it still stays ndarry ?

Comment: @user1243255 you can append `.tolist()` if you want a list.

Answer (score 3):

`ndarray.flatten` exists for this purpose.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([np.array([[ 1.16179327, -0.1721163 ]])], dtype=object)
>>> a.flatten()
array([1.16179327, -0.1721163], dtype=object)
```

or

```
>>> a.flatten().tolist()
[1.16179327, -0.1721163]
```

Comment: Print your `a`.  It won't display the same as the OP `RCoeff`.  Your `a` has shape `(1,1,2)`.

Comment: Weird, maybe the display is different because of that ide/interpreter OP is using? Looking at the output the OP is getting, I wonder if `RCoeff.flatten().flatten().tolist()` will do it. Waiting for clarification.

Comment: >>> z = ARCoeff.flatten().flatten().tolist()
>>> type(z)
Out[38]: list
>>> z1 = z[0]
>>> type(z1)
Out[40]: numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the built-in [.tolist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method?

```
>>> RCoeff.tolist()
```

Comment: this will give you a nested list `[[[1.16179327, -0.1721163]]]`.